# How to download excel file with axios vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

On the controller I return a path to where the excel file is located..Now I want to download that file

Below is my code:

```
reportExcel(val) {
  axios
    .get("/algn/api/report/" + val)
    .then((res) => {
      var url = res.data; // http://localhost.local/public/files/data.xlsx
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = url.split("/").pop();
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

I am getting the error as "Excel cannot open the file "data.xlsx" because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file". (The original excel file is still usable).

I have tried all the solutions which I found in google but nothing worked. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you get the correct file if you access `http://localhost/algn/api/report/val` from browser or postman?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
reportExcel(val) {
  axios
    // add responseType
    .get("/algn/api/report/" + val, {responseType : 'blob'}) 
    .then((res) => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]));
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      const filename = `file.xlsx`;
      a.setAttribute('download', filename);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Assuming the link gives correct excel file, we can inform that it is file (not the usual JSON) by specifying `{responseType : 'blob'}` in the request. Then, create the  file using `window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]))`. The rest is small adjustments to handle file instead of text.